# Split a string and create a new column with the result of that split using BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery `students` table that contains informations regarding students. The structure of the table is the following:

```
id - SRING
gpa - STRING
classesA - STRING
classesB - STRING
```

**sample rows**

```
id - "STU03827"
gpa - "3.80"
classesA - "history, math, physics"
classesB - "french, chinese" 
-----------
id - "STU29025"
gpa - "3.21"
classesA - ""
classesB - "spanish, italian"
```

**expected output**

```
id - "STU03827"
gpa - "3.80"
classesA - "history, math, physics"
classesB - "french, chinese" 
classID - "history"
-----------
id - "STU03827"
gpa - "3.80"
classesA - "history, math, physics"
classesB - "french, chinese" 
classID - "math"
-----------
id - "STU03827"
gpa - "3.80"
classesA - "history, math, physics"
classesB - "french, chinese" 
classID - "physics"
-----------
id - "STU03827"
gpa - "3.80"
classesA - "history, math, physics"
classesB - "french, chinese" 
classID - "french"
-----------
id - "STU03827"
gpa - "3.80"
classesA - "history, math, physics"
classesB - "french, chinese" 
classID - "chinese"
-----------
id - "STU29025"
gpa - "3.21"
classesA - ""
classesB - "spanish, italian" 
classID - "spanish"
-----------
id - "STU29025"
gpa - "3.21"
classesA - ""
classesB - "spanish, italian" 
classID - "italian"
```

What I am trying to achieve is using `SELECT` and `WITH AS`, selecting the `students` table and add a new column which is `classId`. classId correspond to the current iteration. For instance, if a given record has a total of 5 items between `classesA` and `classesB`, I should see that record 5 types with only a single difference, the `classId`.

**What I have so far**

```
SELECT id as id,
classesA as classesA ,
classesB as classesB ,
SPLIT(classesA , ",") as classes
FROM students
WHERE classesA <> ""
UNION ALL
SELECT id as id,
classesA as classesA ,
classesB as classesB ,
SPLIT(classesB, ",") as classes
FROM students
WHERE classesB <> ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative option

```
select * from students, 
unnest(split(classesA, ', ') || split(classesB, ', ')) as classID
where classID != ''
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
with sample as (
    select "STU03827" as id, "3.80" as gpa, "history, math, physics" as classesA, "french, chinese" as classesB
    union all 
    select "STU29025", "3.21", "", "spanish, italian"
)

select sample.*, classId 
from sample, UNNEST(split(concat(classesA,", ", classesB ))) as classId
where classId <> "";
```